# How to handle data duplicated due to same cases remaining each month in SPSS

Tags: datatable, spss

I am writing a thesis on Airbnb's presence in Ireland and its effect on house prices. I've downloaded data from InsideAirbnb (.CSV), which describes each Airbnb host and house on a monthly basis. Each host has a unique host_id, each house has a unique house_id, and each host can have multiple house_id's.

Due it being monthly statistics, the same users are documented each month which causes duplicates when the tables are merged. These duplicates have the exact same data columns except the date (written in format mmm yyyy) and the Row_ID.

I'm not sure how to handle this data as obviously it is inaccurate due to the duplicated data. Is there a way to group the data based on the date, or should I have an array of date values in a single column for each? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify - (a) what are you trying to merge this data with? what is the structure of the other table? and finally - are you going to analyse houses, of hosts?

Comment: I first merged all the tables available for download (theres about 6 months per year available). These include lat & long values so I then joined this with a spatial file describing the relative Eircodes (post codes in Ireland) which enclose the lat long values. I am also able to attain data on house prices depending on Eircodes (.CSV), which will be my next step after handling the duplicated data. My aim is to analyse the change of house prices in Ireland since Airbnb began and see if there's a correlation. This includes all houses, not just host's houses.

Comment: So it sounds like you know how to merge the files, but what you are seeking is not programming advice (which is the topic for this site) but statistical advice? If that's true you should move the question to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)